# Magento 1.9.2.2 {{store url}} link not working

Tags: url, permissions, ce-1.9.2.2

I'm trying to insert a link to the My Account page into a static block. I'm using the following format:

```
<a href="{{store url="customer/account"}}">My account</a>
```

While in previous versions of Magento this works fine, as of 1.9.2.2 this doesn't work anymore.

After checking the release notes I have added the static block ('cms/block') in System > Permissions > Blocks. I have also added every combination of 'store', 'url' and 'store/url' in System > Permissions > Blocks.

I have searched extensively to try and find a solution, but I'm probably using the wrong keywords (luckily the 'store' keyword isn't very common in combination with 'Magento'...). What do I have to do to make links work in static blocks in Magento 1.9.2.2?

Comment: `<a href="{{store url='customer/account'}}">My account</a>` try that..

Answer (score 0):

try like that sometime "" create problem

```
<a href="{{store url='customer/account'}}">My account</a>
```

Comment: I forgot to add that I already tried using single quotes/double quotes in every possible combination. This also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a ->getContent() instead of ->toHtml(), which doesn't replace any variables.